# Converter DTO para Entity Java

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa-2.0, ejb

Estou com o seguinte problema, estou tentando criar um método que converta **DTO's** para **Entity's** e vice versa ate o momento cheguei no seguinte método que converte perfeitamente quando são atributos compatíveis *String* para *String*, *Long* para *Long* e etc. Claro sendo a premissa que os tipos que quero converter sempre sejam iguais.

```
public static <T> void ConvertDtoToEntity(T dto, T entity){
    Field[] entitycampos = entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    Field[] dtocampos = dto.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field entityfield : entitycampos) {
        entityfield.setAccessible(true);
        for (Field dtofield : dtocampos) { 
            dtofield.setAccessible(true);               
            if(!entityfield.getName().equals("serialVersionUID") 
                && entityfield.getName().equals(dtofield.getName()))
            {
                try {
                    entityfield.set(entity, dtofield.get(dto));
                    break;
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Só que o problema está na hora de converter List, Set e ou outros dtos ou outras entitys que estão dentro daquele dto.
EX DTO que convert perfeitamente para uma entity:

```
public class CupomHistoricoDto implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BigDecimal seqcupomhistorico;
    private int quantidade;
    private Date data;
    private long nroempresa;
```

EX Entity que convert perfeitamente para uma dto:

```
public class CupomHistoricoEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "SEQCUPOMHISTORICO", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal seqcupomhistorico;

    @Column(name = "QUANTIDADE", nullable = false)
    private int quantidade;

    @Column(name = "DATA", nullable = false)
    private Date data;

    @Column(name = "NROEMPRESA", nullable = false)
    private long nroempresa;
```

EX DTO que não esta convertendo para um entity

```
public class CupomHistoricoDto implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BigDecimal seqcupomhistorico;
    private int quantidade;
    private Date data;
    private long nroempresa;
    private CupomHistoricoDetalheDto detalhe;
```

EX Entity

```
public class CupomHistoricoEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "SEQCUPOMHISTORICO", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal seqcupomhistorico;

    @Column(name = "QUANTIDADE", nullable = false)
    private int quantidade;

    @Column(name = "DATA", nullable = false)
    private Date data;

    @Column(name = "NROEMPRESA", nullable = false)
    private long nroempresa;

    @OneToOne  
    @JoinColumn(name = "seqdetalhe", referencedColumnName = "SEQDETALHE")
    private CupomHistoricoDetalheEntity detalhe;
```

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como implementar esse método ou já tenha feito algo semelhante.

OBS: estou testando se consigo fazer o que eu quero utilizando o BeanUtils da apache.

Comment: Você está tentando clonar objetos, certo? Para fazer uma "clonagem profunda" (*deep clone*), você pode serializar e desserializar um objeto ou pode usar uma biblioteca especializada em clonagem. Veja: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html e http://code.google.com/p/cloning/. Não entendi onde "Entity" e "DTO" entram nessa história - veja que uma enitity desatachada eventualmente já pode ser considerada um DTO. Se você explicar seu objetivo talvez possamos apontar solução mais simples.

Comment: @Caffé
Aqui na empresa temos a camada de Entity e a Dto e usamos a Dto para transitar as informações, e na serviço que convertemos para dto~entity para trabalhar com a base e entity~dto para transitar com as informações, fazemos assim pois usamos muitos campos no dtos que são impertinentes na entity. Esse método de trabalho já é um modo antigo de se trabalhar aqui, só que querem agora agilizar a conversão dos objetos, o método que fiz acima faz uma parte mas não para os objetos dentro deles. Olhei o apache mas ele também não atende, ele faz o que fiz acima.

Comment: Não faz o mesmo que você porque ele faz um *deep cloning* (desde que todas as classes sejam serializáveis) enquanto você está fazendo um *shallow cloning*. De qualquer modo o mais indicado é a clonagem mais performática que indiquei no segundo link, já que não exige que as classes sejam serializáveis e já que serializar e desserializar é bem custoso.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que o melhor para o seu caso é fazer manualmente. Criar um mecanismo próprio para fazer essa conversão, uma vez que você conhece perfeitamente os DTOs e as Entitys e como você mesmo disse: "usamos muitos campos no dtos que são impertinentes na entity". Com um mecanismo criado por si e especifico poderás controlar o que passa de DTO para Entity e vice versa uma vez que nem tudo do DTO tem que passar para Entity respectiva. 
Faça algo mais ou menos assim:

1. Crie uma interface

   ```
   public interface Conveter
   {   
      public GenericDTO convertFromEntity(GenericEntity entity);
      public GenericEntity convertFromDTO(GenericDTO dto);
   }
   ```
2. Crie implementações para cada um dos seus tipos (DTO-Entity)

   ```
    public CupomHistoricoConverter implements Converter
    {
       @Override
       public GenericDTO convertFromEntity(GenericEntity entity)
       {
         // Faça aqui a conversão manual campo a campo de entity para dto
       }

       @Override
       public GenericEntity convertFromDTO(GenericDTO dto)
       {
         // Faça aqui a conversão manual campo a campo de  dto para entity
       }
   }
   ```

É um pouco trabalhoso, mas é melhor porque ai você tem o total controle do que está a acontecer e do que deve ser realmente convertido.

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo o raciocínio da solução anterior, ainda podemos deixar parametrizado para evitar casting na hora de implementar os conversores.

```
public interface Converter<DTO extends GenericDTO, ENT extends GenericEntity> {

        public DTO convertFromEntity(ENT entity);
        public ENT convertFromDTO(DTO dto);

}



public CupomHistoricoConverter implements Converter <CupomHistoricoDTO, CupomHistoricoEntity> 
 {
    @Override
    public CupomHistoricoDTO convertFromEntity(CupomHistoricoEntity entity)
    {
      // Faça aqui a conversão manual campo a campo de entity para dto
    }

    @Override
    public CupomHistoricoEntity convertFromDTO(CupomHistoricoDTO dto)
    {
      // Faça aqui a conversão manual campo a campo de  dto para entity
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use o dozer

`<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
    <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>`

`Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
EntidadeDestino entidade =  mapper.map(entidadeOrigem, EntidadeDestino.class);`

Comment: Considere adicionar uma breve explicação do por que a sua resposta resolve o problema.